# Python: is there a way to tell the program to go back?

Tags: python

I’ve been wondering is there a way to code a line that tells python to go back to somewhere else in the code?

Something like this:

```
choose = int(input())
if choose == 1:
    print(“Hi.”)
else:
*replay line1*
```

Something really basic like that?

I don’t particularly want to have to use a bigger loop but I can if possible?

Any ideas, I’m really new to python?

Comment: You have to use a loop.

Comment: The term your looking for is _control flow statement_. And yes, Python has some. As @AndrewLi already said, you can use a loop to accomplish this.

Comment: Fundamentally, you are looking for a control structure that is no-longer widely used in modern programming languages: the `GOTO` statement. This is because of the advent of [structured programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming). You should use a loop for this.

Answer (score 2):

```
choose = 0
while (choose != 1)
    choose = int(input())
    if choose == 1:
        print(“Hi.”)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a weird one and it is suited for cases where the value is expected to boolean (two expected values only), and those boolean values are either 0 or 1, and not some other arbitrary string, *aaand* where you don't want to store the input.

```
while int(input()) != 1:
    # <logic for else>
    pass  # only put this if there's no logic for the else.

print("Hi!")
```

Though there are alternative methods such as:

```
choose = int(input())
while choose != 1:
    <logic for else>
    choose = int(input())
```

Or you could create a function:

```
def poll_input(string, expect, map_fn=str):
    """
    Expect := list/tuple of comparable objects
    map_fn := Function to map to input to make checks equal
    """

    if isinstance(expect, str):
        expect = (expect,)

    initial = map_fn(input(string))
    while initial not in expect:
        initial = map_fn(input(string))

    return initial
```

And thus use it as such:

```
print("You picked %d!" % poll_input("choice ", (1, 2, 3), int))
```

For more ambiguous cases